# How to join three tables using Codeigniter if there is no common fields?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

Lets assume my Mysql tables are

**Table 1 - Deposit Details**

> id   |    deposit_type  | amount  | deposit_master_id
>
> 1  |    Fixed                    | 100000  | 1

**Table 2 - Deposit Master**

> deposit_master_id |    bank_id  |    branch_id
>
> 1                             |    1             |    2

**Table 3 - Bank Master**

> bank_id  |    bank_name
>
> 1            | SBI

I know the basic SQL Join operations in Codeigniter and I did it also.But here comes a scenerio that there is no common field for these three tables , but I think they can join, but I don't have any clues.
How can I get **Bank Name** from **Bank Master** through **Deposit Details**?

Sample Output

> id  |    bank_name
>
> 1    | SBI

Comment: Hmm... `deposit_master_id` (Table 1 - Deposit Details) => `deposit_master_id` (Table 2 - Deposit Master) => `bank_id` (bank_id)

Comment: Yes, this is the output i want.

Comment: What's the problem? Use 2 `JOIN`s. What have you already done to solve this?

Comment: I can't join beacause there is no common fileds in these three tables,but there is  **Table 1 & Table 2** and **Table 2 & Table 3** having common fileds.

Comment: Provide some sample data and expected output...

Comment: @Ajay - I Updated my question.Please check.

Comment: how u want the output

Comment: what it the deposit_master_id value in Deposit Details table it is null or some another values

Comment: @Ajay - deposit_master_id value in Deposit Details table  is the deposit_master_id number of table Deposit Master

Comment: here u can write a simple join query to get the expected output

Comment: @SudhiSr, you can have multi-`JOIN` syntax, so you don't need to have one column in all three tables. `JOIN` table1 with table2 and table2 with table3 in the same query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select d.id,bm.bank_name
from Deposit_Details d
inner join Deposit_Master dm on dm.deposit_master_id = d.deposit_master_id
inner join Bank_Master bm on bm.bank_id = dm.bank_id


$this->db->select('Deposit_Details.id,Bank_Master.bank_name');
$this->db->from('Deposit_Details');
$this->db->join('Deposit_Master', 'Deposit_Master.deposit_master_id = Deposit_Details.deposit_master_id');
$this->db->join('Bank_Master', 'Bank_Master.bank_id = Deposit_Master.bank_id');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

### Can use the query like this

//select the columns what u want from the tables

```
 $this->db->select('*');
 $this->db->from('Deposit Details dd'); 
    $this->db->join(' Deposit Master dm', 'dd.deposit_master_id=dm.deposit_master_id', 'inner');
    $this->db->join('Bank Master bm ', 'bm.bank_id =dm.bank_id', 'inner');
```

Comment: can u check this